# Can't Install SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019

I've been trying to install SQL Server 2019 for a week now, It keeps giving me the same error. I searched the internet and couldn't find a solid fix for it. It's happening for any version of SQL Server. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me. I'll add the error:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Setup

The following error has occurred:

There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

The summary file contains the information below:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068052293
  Start time:                    2021-02-01 21:55:36
  End time:                      2021-02-01 21:56:16
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC_SDK:        Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Next step for SNAC:            Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  LAPTOP-D6EKGGIP
  Machine processor count:       12
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 Home (10.0.18363)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2019 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2019
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       15
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         C:\SQL2019\Developer_ENU\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Developer

Product Update Status:
  User selected not to include product updates.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210201_215536\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  IACKNOWLEDGEENTCALLIMITS:      false
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              true
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391
  ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:          <empty>
  ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:         <empty>
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISWORKERSVCCERT:               <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCMASTER:             <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:           <empty>
  ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         true
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         <empty>
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Arabic_CI_AS
  SQLJAVADIR:                    <empty>
  SQLMAXDOP:                     12
  SQLMAXMEMORY:                  2147483647
  SQLMINMEMORY:                  0
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         true
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           LAPTOP-D6EKGGIP\tarek
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            8
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE:     false
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 false
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  USESQLRECOMMENDEDMEMORYLIMITS: false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210201_215536\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210201_215536\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210201_215536\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, and then try the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Native Client Access Component
  Component error code:          1723
  Component log file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210201_215536\sqlncli_Cpu64_1.log
  Error description:             There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A DLL required for this installation to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=sqlncli.msi%40RollbackCleanup%401723

Rules with failures or warnings:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20210201_215536\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Here is the link to the log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H2KZtguhM2UiLZv-uDDJbNg19sDpkXrf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: We're gunna need the install logs here. Alsoz what *did*  your support personnel and/or vendor say on the subject?

Comment: Do/did you have a previous version of Microsoft SQL Server installed on your machine? [This](https://shubell.wordpress.com/2018/01/05/installing-microsoft-sql-server-2012-native-client/) might help.

Comment: That link helped me to install SQL Server native client but still the SQL Server 2019 gave the same error on installation ( And to answer your question no I don't have a previous version of SQL Server installed since even when I try to install any version it gives the same error )